# Django i18n uses it's own translations

Tags: django-i18n

I have created a .po file for pl locale and translated all the strings. Everything works allright except for "Log in" string. I translated "Log in" into "Zaloguj" but in HTML it appears as "Zaloguj się" though such translation doesn't even appear in my .po file. I suppose "Log in" is so popular that Django provides out-of-the-box translation (like for error messages) but is it documented anywhere?

I would like to know how can I force using my translation instead of Django's translation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django discovers translations in the following order, trying to achieve that local resources get higher precedence than more global translations. From the docs:

> 1. The directories listed in LOCALE_PATHS have the highest precedence, with the ones appearing first having higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
> 2. Then, it looks for and uses if it exists a locale directory in each of the installed apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS. The ones appearing first have higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
> 3. Finally, the Django-provided base translation in django/conf/locale is used as a fallback.

So I guess the question is if you put your `LOCALE_PATHS` (1) or `INSTALLED_APPS` (2) in the right order. Be aware that third party apps may overrule your own translations if they're put in front of them.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations for more details.